# Is there a way to tell the compiler to optimize to have fewer branches?

Tags: optimization, rust

I am writing smart contracts which are compiled into WASM and have gas-metering added on top of each execution branch. Is there some way to tell the compiler to optimize to have fewer branches to have less gas-metering overhead?